# Accessing files outside document root

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I want to access a directory full of mp3 files that is located outside my root directory of my virtual server.

I have tried numerous different configurations in the virtual host with no luck. The more I read, the more different solutions I see.  None of them work for me.

Here is the best I can manage

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.dmdefd.com

    ServerName www.dmdefd.767

    <Directory "/var/www/www.dmdefd.com">
       allow from all
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

alias /mp3music '/media/dmd/DUsers/music'



    <Directory "/media/dmd/DUsers/music">
       #Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks - no help
       Options +Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I restart Apache and I then try to access the files from PHP with

```
<?php
   $root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
   $time = new Datetime();
   echo $time->format ("H:i:s")."<br>";

   echo $root."<br>";
   echo realpath ("$root/mp3music")."<br>";

   $biglist = scandir ("$root/mp3music/");

?>
```

and the result is

```
Warning: scandir(/var/www/www.dmdefd.com/mp3music/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /var/www/www.dmdefd.com/musicmanager/aliases.php on line 9

Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in /var/www/www.dmdefd.com/musicmanager/aliases.php on line 9
```

Please note that the virtual server works fine, I just can't get to the files.

Comment: Did you try soft- or hardlinking the directory? Apache won't get out of its docroot afaik

Comment: Hard linking does not work.  You are supposed to be able to access files outside document root.  There are numerous examples on Stack Overflow.  I just can't get it to work.

Comment: I know that I tried to do the same and failed, time ago. As far as I remember, It was due to the fact that somewhere in the core config there is a directory which locks in apache to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code looks for your on-disk music under the DOCUMENT_ROOT CGI variable. There is only one DOCUMENT_ROOT -- it doesn't change if you happen to access files via an Alias or mod_userdir.

Apache has a relatively recent/priority addition in 2.4 called CONTEX_DOCUMENT_ROOT which would be the prefix supplied by an Alias directive.

Other then that, you could just set your own environment variable in the Apache config, or let your PHP code know where your music lives directly.